# How to find relative path to C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts\ADSUTIL.VBS?

Tags: iis, iis-6, metabase, installscript, adsutil.vbs

IIS 6 and older ships with a utility script called [ADSUTIL.VBS](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d3df4bc9-0954-459a-b5e6-7a8bc462960c.mspx?mfr=true):

> Adsutil.vbs is an IIS administration
>   utility that uses Microsoft Visual
>   Basic Scripting Edition (VBScript)
>   with Active Directory Service
>   Interfaces (ADSI) to manipulate the
>   IIS configuration. This script should
>   be run using CScript, which is
>   installed with Windows Script Host.

In other words, this tool lets you change [IIS metabase](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779862%28WS.10%29.aspx) settings programmatically, from the command line.

I would like to call this tool from an InstallShield project in order to make some configuration changes to IIS. I am curious if it either legal to re-distribute the script (there is no legal wording inside the source for it) or to simply launch the command via:

```
CSCRIPT %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs
```

and hope that the script exists on disk in that location.

**So my question is** - will it always exist in that path above, even if some other websites (inetpub roots) on the machine are located on a non-system drive? It seems all MSDN and other Microsoft KB articles that refer to the ADSUTIL tool do so by using the %SYSTEMDRIVE% path above.

I see that at least [one other attempt to deal with this](http://community.acresso.com/archive/index.php?t-93165.html) by distributing both cscript.exe and adsutil.vbs with their InstallShield projects.

Perhaps there is a registry key or other method to obtain the location of the Inetpub\AdminScripts path?

Maybe I should just write a [C# application that changes the value](http://www.codersource.net/csharp_iis_metabase.html) or [my own VBScript](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/4b976f46-3751-4f6b-ab68-5e19fa73a7b1.mspx?pf=true) and distribute with my own little app instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked in [JShumaker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262921/how-to-find-relative-path-to-c-inetpub-adminscripts-adsutil-vbs/1269043#1269043) to solve the problem. The best route seems to be the following InstallScript function that I call to run a batch script:

```
prototype SetIISValues();   
function SetIISValues()  
    string szProgram, szCmd;
begin                              
    szProgram = TARGETDIR + "SetIISValues.bat";
    szCmd = "";  
    LaunchAppAndWait (szProgram, szCmd, LAAW_OPTION_WAIT);
end;
```

The batch script calls this:

```
@echo off
cscript.exe SetIISValues.vbs
```

And the VBScript looks like this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim IIsObject
Set IIsObject = GetObject("IIS://localhost/w3svc/1")
IIsObject.Put "Name", "Value"
IIsObject.Setinfo
```

Doing it this way relieves the need to use ADSUTIL.VBS as part of the installation - the (relative) path to it is irrelevant if you don't need to use it.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue recently and decided to just rework a small bit of vbscript to use in a custom action in an msi installer.  It can take a bit to figure out the core of how adsutil.vbs does things, but it is deently well writen.  For example, i needed to switch an application pool to Classic instead of Integrated mode and explicitly set it to run in 32-bit mode when on 64-bit windows,  in distilled form this resulted in this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim IIsObject
Set IIsObject = GetObject("IIS://LocalHost/W3SVC/AppPools/TestPool")
IIsObject.Put "ManagedPipelineMode", 1
IIsObject.Setinfo
IIsObject.Put "Enable32BitAppOnWin64", CBool("True")
IIsObject.Setinfo
```

Comment: I guess I'll take the bait and go that route instead (write my own vbscript and distribute that). I'll post my own answer and credit your suggestion.